# Is the inequality of the random matrices correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-matrices

I am not familiar with random matrices but I need to confirm the correctness of the inequality below.

> Let $\xi_i\in\{\pm 1\}$ be independent  random signs, and let
> $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ be $m\times m$ Hermitian matrices. Let $\sigma^2 = \|\sum_{i=1}^n Var[\xi_i]A_i^2\|$. Then
> $$Pr\bigg(\bigg\|\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[\xi_i]A_i-\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_iA_i\bigg\|\geq
>  t\sigma\bigg)\leq2m\exp(-t^2/2).$$

It is said to be cited from the paper "[User-Friendly Tail Bounds for Sums of Random
Matrices](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emontanar/TEACHING/Stat319/PAPERS/tropp2012user.pdf)
". But I cannot find which results in that paper can imply the inequality. Is the inequality correct?

Comment: Realizing my answer assumes that $\xi_i$ are $\pm1$ each with probability 0.5. Not sure if that's an assumption in your context as well, so thought I would write a comment about it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not correct.

Take random variable $\xi_i$ as $\mathbb{P}(\xi_i=1)=1$ for each $i$. Then $Var[\xi_i]=0$ for each $i$ and thus $\sigma = 0$. l.h.s. hold with probability $1$ while r.h.s is smaller than $1$ is take $t$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's a corollary of their Theorem 1.5. I'll restate that inequality and work it into the form you have.

To avoid a conflict of notation, I'm going to change the notation in the paper you linked such that $t\mapsto\alpha$ and $\sigma\mapsto\sigma_0$, and I will hold your notation fixed. Also, that theorem is stated for the rectangular case where $\mathbf{B}_k$ has dimension $d_1\times d_2$. Here we have $d_1=d_2=m$, and I've simplified my restatement of their theorem below to match the square case.

In that notation, the inequality in Theorem 1.2. reads

$$P\bigg( \bigg\| \sum_k \xi_k \mathbf{B}_k \bigg\| \geq \alpha\bigg) \leq 2m \cdot e^{-\alpha^2/2\sigma_0^2},$$
where $\xi_k$ are either independent standard Gaussian or independent Rademacher (which is the same as random signs as you have), and where $\sigma_0^2=\left\| \sum_k \mathbf{B}_k^2 \right\|$ (that's the square version of their definition of $\sigma_0$).

Now it's just a game of translating this equality into yours. First, let $t=\alpha/\sigma_0$. Then the inequality becomes
$$P\bigg( \bigg\| \sum_k \xi_k \mathbf{B}_k \bigg\| \geq t\sigma_0\bigg) \leq 2m \cdot e^{-t^2/2}.$$
That's a first step.

Now let's deal with the $\mathbb{E}\xi$ sum. Clearly $\mathbb{E}\xi=0$, since $\xi$ takes values $\pm1$ with equal probability. So, the first sum $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[\xi]A_i$ is identically 0. Thus it does not affect the inequality at all. Even better, the variance of the Rademacher variates is $0.5\cdot 1^2 + 0.5\cdot (-1)^2=1$, so that $\sigma=\sigma_0$.

So, the inequality you have is exactly the same as the one here, with $A$ changed to $\mathbf{B}$ and some extra terms that have no effect. Let me know if any details need clarification and I'll edit those in.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure this deduction cannot extend to general probability.

Comment: By general probability, do you mean general $p$ parameter for the random signs? If that's what you mean, it really might be able to extend, actually, let me think about it. That might be why we have the change in the definition of $\sigma$, and why we have the $\mathbb{E}\xi$ present.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. The problem is how to modify the proof of this theorem to  general random signs. I don't think it is obvious to do that.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I tried a little bit and didn't see anything